# Text inside <p> after line break <br> ignores css for <p> tag if heading is also present

Tags: html, css, inline, display, html-heading

My goal is to have headings be inline with the text inside of a `<p>` tag... all of which have a `margin` to the padding of the container

I have the following html code

```
<div id='homeContent'>
  <!-- other headings and content here -->

  <p><h3>Heading</h3> some text</br> more text</p>

  <!-- other headings and content here -->
</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
#homeContent h3, #homeContent h4, #homeContent p {
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0px 16px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

#homeContent h3, #homeContent h4 {
  display: inline;
}
#homeContent {
  padding: 0px 16px;
  margin: 32px 0px;
}
```

Here is what I want to happen (considering the code block to be the container border)

```
      H3 HEADING some text
      more text here
```

Here is what I'm actually getting

```
      H3 HEADING some text
  more text here <-- notice here the text does not respect the margin given to the <p> tag
```

Now if I take the heading tag out of the paragraph tag, the paragraph text behaves correctly, but obviously does not appear inline with the heading, which is the goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have any **block level** elements inside `<p>` tag. Even if your code has:

```
<p><h3>Heading</h3> some text</br> more text</p>
```

It renders like this in the browsers:

[image: Browser Dev]

So, it is better to use correct code like:

```
<h3>Heading</h3>
<p> some text</br> more text</p>
```

And style it using CSS.

---

Paragraph and Headings are two different animals. According to what you need in the comments, I would recommend this markup:

```css
h3 {color: red;}
h3 span {font-weight: normal; font-size: 0.8em;}
```

```html
<h3>Heading <span>some text</br> more text</span></h3>
```

And further to your comments, I could find that you wanna make your `<h3>` and `<p>` inline running contents. I would suggest to keep the above markup and use the following CSS:

```css
h3, h3 + p {display: inline-block; /* Or inline */}
```

Comment: I understand that is what's happening... My question is how do I fix it?

Saying "style it accordingly" is like saying, answer your own question.

Comment: You will need to `display: inline` your `p` tag as well as the `h3`. By default, `p` tags are display as block elements which means they show up on a new line. In addition to that, you'll have to remove the margin you're seeting up in the line below `z-index`.

Comment: @Constantine Try this: `<h3>Heading <span>some text</br> more text</span></h3>`. I believe this is better than what you have. And give different styling to `h3 span {}`.

Comment: If I make the `<p>` have `display: inline` it breaks the rest of my content... since I actually want the `<p>` to be a paragraph i.e. a block of text

Comment: @Constantine Try `h3, h3 + p {display: inline;}`.

Comment: Use a span as suggested by @Praveen Kumar. That is a more appropriate method of getting what you're after.

Comment: I ended up using `<span>` inside the `<h3>` tag... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

```
<div id='homeContent'>
  <!-- other headings and content here -->
<div class="heading">
  <h3>Heading</h3> <p class="p-heading1">Some text</p>
  <p class="p-heading2">More text here</p>
</div>
  <!-- other headings and content here -->
</div>
```

```
#homeContent h3, #homeContent h4, #homeContent p {
  z-index: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.heading{
  margin-left:16px;
}

#homeContent h3, #homeContent h4, .p-heading1{
  display: inline-block;
}
#homeContent {
  padding: 0px 16px;
  margin: 32px 0px;
}
```

Here's a JsFiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tqx2h8e3/)